# How to remove line breaks after "ctime" in C program?

Tags: c

Please bear with me since I'm still really new to C programming. When I run this code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    while (1) {
        time_t mytime;
        mytime = time(NULL);
        printf("%s Hello world\n", ctime(&mytime));
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output always looks like this:

```
Wed Jan 18 02:32:32 2017
 Hello world
Wed Jan 18 02:32:33 2017
 Hello world
Wed Jan 18 02:32:34 2017
 Hello world
```

What I want is like this:

```
Wed Jan 18 02:32:32 2017 Hello world
Wed Jan 18 02:32:33 2017 Hello world
Wed Jan 18 02:32:34 2017 Hello world
```

How can I do that ?

Note:
If I remove `\n` from `printf("%s Hello world\n", ctime(&mytime));` it'll result like this:

```
Wed Jan 18 02:38:29 2017
 Hello worldWed Jan 18 02:38:30 2017
 Hello worldWed Jan 18 02:38:31 2017
 Hello worldWed Jan 18 02:38:32 2017
 Hello worldWed Jan 18 02:38:33 2017
```

Comment: OP doesn't want a line break *before* `Hello World`; desired output includes the one after it.

Comment: Use `strftime` instead of `ctime`.

Comment: Guys you got me wrong, please see my post again

Comment: You will have to copy the output of `ctime` to some string, and replace the last character with `\0`.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I see. The format of `ctime` is well defined; just remove the trailing newline. (That's indeed a stupid addition of `asctime`; linebreaks should be left to the user)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ctime` function will return a pointer to a string which ends in a newline.

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime):

> The call `ctime(t)` is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(t))`. It converts
>   the calendar time t into a null-terminated string of the form
>       "Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993\n"

If you don't want the newline, you need to save the pointer and remove the newline before printing.

```
char *t = ctime(&mytime);
if (t[strlen(t)-1] == '\n') t[strlen(t)-1] = '\0';
printf("%s Hello world\n", t);
```

Comment: But is it guaranteed to be a `\n` and never a `\r\n` across different systems?

Comment: @Havenard Yes, the C standard also states the above equivalence between `ctime` and `asctime` and output format for `asctime`.

Comment: Reasonable.  Yet why the test for `t[strlen(t)-1] == '\n'`?  If code is not confident that the `'\n` ends the buffer, then it should not be confident that `'\n'` even exist and the bad string could begin with `'\0'` which leads to UB with `t[strlen(t)-1]`.

Comment: Simpler solution, works in all cases: `t[strcspn(t, "\r\n")] = '\0';`

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem so the workaround I figured was using `strtok()` in the `string.h` library. This will omit `'\n'` and store the whole token before it:

```
char *p = strtok(ctime(&mytime), '\n');
```

Comment: '\n' should be "\n"

Answer (score 3):

Use [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) to format your own string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[100];
    strftime(buf, 100, "%a %b %d %T %Y", localtime(&(time_t){time(NULL)}));
    printf("%s Hello world\n", buf);
}
```

For simple formatting tasks like the one in the question, you can spare yourself the `printf` and let `strftime` do all the work:

```
    strftime(buf, 100, "%a %b %d %T %Y Hello world\n",
             localtime(&(time_t){time(NULL)}));
    fputs(buf, stdout);
```

You should also check the return value of `strftime`, zero may indicate failure.

Comment: It does look like a more appropriate solution than messing around with `ctime()`'s static buffer.

Comment: @Havenard `"%a %b %d %T %Y"` is locale dependent, `ctime()` is not.

Comment: @chux: Specifically, `%a` and `%b` are locale-dependent; the other parts are not.

Comment: @KerrekSB Nice use of the C99 compound literal  `(time_t){time(NULL)}` to provide an address to the returned `time_t` from `time()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 simple solutions:

- store the pointer returned by `ctime()` and overwrite the trailing newline with:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        time_t mytime;
        mytime = time(NULL);
        char *p = ctime(&mytime);
        p[strcspn(p, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("%s Hello world\n", p);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- even simpler: just print the first 24 characters of the string returned by `ctime()`:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        time_t mytime;
        mytime = time(NULL);
        printf("%.24s Hello world\n", ctime(&mytime));
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The date format produced by ctime is "Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy" so you'll want to use `%.24s` to strip the new-line and null-character at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Lop off the `'\n'` in the popular fashion as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2410359) after `fgets()`.  It does not even have a problem if `'\n'` is missing.

```
char * ct = ctime(&mytime));
ct[strcspn(ct, "\n")] = '\0';
printf("%s Hello world\n", ct);
```

---

`ctime()` nominally returns a pointer to `static char some_name[26];` in the following example form

```
Sun Sep 16 01:03:52 1973\n\0
```

The C spec has a qualifier about `struct tm` fields values being in their *normal ranges*, else the results are UB.  Going on the idea that the year *could* be outside the range 1000-9999, this renders the fixed placement of `'\n'` problematic.